# Roxygen 2 do not edit by hand vs notes: add ...to NAMESPACES

Tags: r

NAMESPACES file generated automatically by Roxygen2 cannot be edited by hand. However, notes tells me to add code to NAMESPACE file.

When making a new R package using roxygen2, the NAMESPACES file is generated automatically and cannot be edited by hand. However, when I run check, I got the notes telling me to add code to NAMESPACE file

> checking R code for possible problems ... NOTE
>    myFunction1: no visible global function definition for 'combn'
>    myFunction2: no visible global function definition for 'chisq.test'
>    myFunction3: no visible global function definition for 'rbinom'
>    Undefined global functions or variables:
>      chisq.test combn rbinom
>    Consider adding
>      importFrom("stats", "chisq.test", "rbinom")
>      importFrom("utils", "combn")
>    to your NAMESPACE file.

Should I follow the notes to edit NAMESPACES file by hand or just follow the roxygen2? If I edit, how should I get rid of Roxygen2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The note to edit your NAMESPACE file is because that's what you would do if you didn't use roxygen. Since you are a roxygen user, you instead add the `@importFrom` directive to an R source file:

```r
#' @importFrom stats chisq.test rbinom
#' @importFrom utils combn
NULL
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused about "adding directive to an R source file". Since I would upload this package to CRAN, should I pack it together to the "gz"?

Comment: As in, add those lines to one of the .R files in your package.

Comment: By adding to one .R file is enough? A random one? or all those which used these funcitons

Comment: BTW, as a few people have said to you now: if an answer solves your problem, upvote and/or accept it by ticking the checkmark on the left

Comment: Is it like this? I'm a new in stackoverflow

Comment: Yep, that's it. You also get reputation points for accepting answers, so keep doing it!